# Large wavelength moving very fast or smaller wavelength moving slow

Tags: acoustics, doppler-effect

I was reading a book, which derives the final frequency due to doppler effect for sound.
It states

> ...if the source is moving, the effective wavelength of sound will be changed...
> $$f' = f\left(\frac{v_{sound}}{v_{sound} - v_{source}}\right)$$

and

> ...for a moving observer, the relative velocity of sound is changed...
> $$f' = f\left(\frac{v_{sound} - v_{obs.}}{v_{sound}}\right)$$

clearly these two are different things as the expression of final frequency is different .

How can these two be differentiated by our ear, which gets only the amplitude at an instant(and maybe find frequency/wavelength by rate of change of amplitude)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can these two be differentiated by our ear, which gets only the amplitude at an instant(and maybe find frequency/wavelength by rate of change of amplitude)?

This seems to be the core of your question, which means that (despite your framing around the Doppler shift) you're really asking about how human hearing works and how we differentiate between different frequencies.  What follows is a *very rough* description of this mechanism. (I'm not a biologist, merely a physicist interested in sound & perception.  I have probably oversimplified a lot below, and I welcome corrections if I've gotten any of the following details wrong.)

Physically, the human ear acts like a set of resonators, each of which respond to a particular frequency range.  Sound waves in air enter the ear canal and impact the eardrum, which transmits these vibrations to fluid-filled channel inside the [cochlea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochlea).  Abutting these channels is the organ of Corti, which can sense vibrations in the fluid.

Importantly, the channels inside the cochlea gradually narrow along their length.  This has the result that the fluid at a particular spot in the cochlea will effectively resonate at a particular frequency determined by the width of the channel at that spot.  So if the organ of Corti senses a fluid vibration at one spot in the channel, it transmits a nerve signal that our brain interprets as "there's a low-frequency sound";  if it senses a vibration at another spot in the channel, it sends a signal that the brain interprets as "there's a high-frequency sound".

In other words, the ear does not work as a digital microphone does, simply recording the amplitude of the sound as a function of time.  There is effectively a "physical Fourier transform" performed within the inner ear that allows us to differentiate between frequencies.

Answer (score 2):

During a one second "instant", the pressure amplitude changes many times, enough times.

From an original $100 ~ \text{Hz}$ signal from a moving source in your direction at $0.1 \cdot c$ you hear $100 \cdot \frac{1}{0.9} = 111$ beats. Your brain can count the difference between $100$ and $111$ beats in a second.

If you are moving away from the source, you hear $100 \cdot 0.9 = 90$ beats.